# C++ passing const bool by reference

Tags: c++, function, boolean, pass-by-reference

Is it worth to pass bool by reference ?

```
void foo(const bool& iflag);
```

vs

```
void foo(const bool iflag);
```

I heard bool reference take much time than bool declaration, but I could not check it.

Comment: What are the odds this will ever be an issue worth worrying about?

Comment: Here's an example of [generated assembly for GCC](https://godbolt.org/g/8Txx6q). One is clearly going to be a less costly access.

Comment: _"I could not check it."_ Why not? What did you try? Can't you write tests or simply check the generated code?

Comment: Only if  foo is intended to set iflag but you should remove *const* then.  Using *const* with the second version is redundant because it's pass by value anyway. I personally prefer returning values from a function but if a function returns more than one value, pass-by-reference may come in handy.

Comment: sorry but if you have no way to measure the difference then the question is rather pointless, because the answer only matters if you could see a difference

Answer (score 1):

I'd always pass it by value, unless I wanted to defeat implicit conversions at the calling site, in which case `const` reference could be a sensible choice.

As for *performance* reasons though, if you're in any doubt, check the generated assembly. Instinct suggests to me a potential overhead in the case of the reference, although a compiler might optimise out the mess.

Interestingly though the C++ standard does not mandate a size for `bool`; it *could* be absolutely enormous in an intentionally hostile compiler. Plus the standard provides no mechanism for inspecting the size of a reference: `sizeof(T&)` is always `sizeof(T)`.

Comment: ..at the same time C++ standard does not mandate a size for a reference, right?

Comment: @tobi303: worse than that, the standard gives you no way to check, since the sizeof a reference to T is sizeof(T).

Comment: And a reference doesn't even have to take up space (implementation dependent) so sizeof(ref) is kind of abstract.

Comment: _"the standard provides no mechanism for inspecting the size of a reference"_ but you can see the implementation-defined size used to represent a reference by putting it as the only member of a structure and checking the `sizeof` that. of course, it's going to be a pointer, in practice. And, of course, under _as-if_ it might be optimised away altogether - but then so might any other structure, so I don't think being a reference is special in this regard.

Comment: I guess they coudn't have done it (sizeof(ref) being zero) because new T actually calls new (sizeof(T)) so we'd end up not having an object at all.

Comment: @dsp_user How is `new` relevant to a reference member?

Comment: It was just a response to Bathsheba's comment (which he deleted in the meantime), so just ignore my last comment.